# why does a one-digit array return zero? mergesort testing

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void merge(int a[], int start, int pivot, int finish){
  int *tmp = new int[finish - start +1] ;
  int I = start ;
  int J = pivot +1 ;
  int K = 0 ;
  while((I <= pivot)&& ( J <= finish) ){
    if(a[I] < a[J]){
      tmp[K] = a[I] ; 
      K++ ; I++ ;
    }
    else{
      tmp[K] = a[J] ; K++ ; J++ ;

    }
  }
  if(I <= pivot){
    while(I <= pivot){
      tmp[K++] = a[I++] ;
    }
  }
  if( J<= finish){
    while(J<= finish){
      tmp[K++] = a[J++] ;
    }
  }
  for(K = start ; K <= finish ; K++) a[K] = tmp[K-start] ;
  delete []tmp ;
  return ;   

}

void mergesort(int a[], int start, int finish){
  if(start < finish){
    int pivot = (start + finish)/2 ;
    mergesort(a,start, pivot) ;
    mergesort(a, pivot+1, finish) ;
    merge(a, start, pivot, finish) ;
  }
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {4} ;
     mergesort(test,0, 1) ;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(int); i++) cout<<" * " << test[i] ;
    cout<<endl ;
}
```

when i output this simple test, it prints "* 0". Why zero? where does it come from? the array contains only 4!

Comment: this is just testing mergesort, i m confused, i test my mergesort with one-digit array, and it returns zero!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: I would suggest that the call to `mergesort(test,0, 1) ;` is changing the content of the array before the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the merge sort routine such that both `start` and `finish` are valid positions in the array, but you have invoked the routine using `finish` as an index to "one past the end".

I think you meant to call `mergesort(test, 0, 0);`

The `0` probably comes from `test[1]` which is not a valid index, and it could in fact contain anything.  It just happened to be `0` which is less than `4` and so your `4` would have been moved off the end of the array.  This is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I figured it out.
when calling 
    test[] = {4} ;
    mergesort(test,0,1) ;

it should be "mergesort(test,0,0)". The reason is: the parameter 'finish' should be the a.length-1.

test[] = {4} ; //declares only the first element
trying to access test[45] , test[100] will give some bad numbers - coming from 'unknown' part of test.
Basically, I want to have both start and finish valid numbers worked on.
test.len = 1 , but the index of it is zero, that's why it is from **zero to zero** essentially - there is no other number to look for; 
if I try to access test[1] - it will get some crappy undeclared number